# Git cloning repository to existing one

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-merge, git-clone

I created a new repository and using git clone cloned it locally. 
Now I have another repository with fresh Content Management System code. 
I need to put the contents of that Content Management System to my newly created project, so I could start working on my new project, how can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

When you say extended modules, did you mean external submodules?  That too might be the answer for your Content Management System repository.  That would be an [external submodule](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) within your new repo.

Comment: i mean Silverstripe CMS with basic modules, for easy start from scratch

Comment: I just need to know how i can add my cms from existing repository to newly created repository i will be working with, let's say i have CMSrepo repository, and i created myproject.com repository, i want to work with myproject.com but use my CMS in it, clone it to myproject.com repository or merge...

Comment: i dont need to use CMS repo in future, i need content of this repo in my new project

Comment: what you are describing suggests a use of _git external submodules_.  This is how you can share and consume the code from one git repo within another.  The only other alternative would be to produce some kind of package from your CMSrepo, and publish it to a local package manager and then pull that package in as part of building the code in your second repo.